# OpenCV ImportError after Ubuntu update

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, importerror, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to Linux and OpenCV, I updated my Ubuntu to 16.04 and now I get `ImportError: No module named 'cv2'`

When I try installing OpenCV I get

`python-opencv is already the newest version (2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

The update also updated my Python, which seems to have caused the problem. CMake (GUI version) had Python3.4 for Python3Dir etc. and needed Python3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same issue. I had done sudo apt-get install python-opencv, but still cv2 could not be imported.

Then I removed the cv2 directory, cv2.so file in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

This solved my issue.